# Replace multiple strings in multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, insert, updates

I'm running a 5.0.8 server.(can't update it at the moment)
I want to change a string that has more than 15 occurrences in different tables, and I need to do that for 30000 strings. I only have in hand a 2-columns table with the "old" and the "new" value. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you run an UPDATE statement that replaces the old value with the new value.

The easiest approach would be to run a separate statement for each column you want to update.

For example:

```
UPDATE mytable t
  JOIN old_new s
    ON t.string_column = s.old_value
   SET t.string_column = s.new_value

UPDATE some_other_table t
  JOIN old_new s
    ON t.some_other_column = s.old_value
   SET t.some_other_column = s.new_value
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comment from OP, I'm suspecting that he's not understanding the suggestion. As a demonstration of what these statements do:

mytable  (target to be updated)

```
id  string_column 
--  -------------
 1  fee
 2  fi
 3  foo
 4  fo
 5  fee
 6  foo
```

old_new (list of old values to be replaced with new values)

```
old_value new_value
--------- ---------
fee       fees
fi        fit
foo       bar
```

A *single* execution of the `UPDATE mytable` statement above would result in new values assigned to `string_column`.

mytable (after UPDATE)

```
id  string_column
--  -------------
 1  fees
 2  fit
 3  bar
 4  fo
 5  fees
 6  bar
```

Note that the UPDATE statement would report 5 rows affected. Row id=4 wouldn't be updated, because there wasn't a value matching `'fo'` in the `old_value` column of the `old_new` table.

---

If any of those columns are involved in foreign key relationships, that adds some complexity. You can temporarily disable enforcement of foreign keys...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

And then perform the updates, and then re-enable enforcement of foreign keys

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I think it is impossible to do that 30000 times. Any suggestions for something like loop triggering from the table I have both old and new string?

Comment: You have 30,000 columns that need to be updated? To get that into a loop, you're going to need a rowsource that provides the table and column names; you'll need a query that returns the names of the 30,000 columns that need to be updated. You may be able to make use of a query against `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: You don't want to run a separate UPDATE statement for each row in the old/new table; it would be hugely inefficient to scan through the target table multiple times to replace one value with another, and then scan through it again, for another value. If the criteria is a "match" of `old_value` to the existing value in the column, that is, an equality comparison between of the existing value in the target column and the `old_value` in your `old_new` table, then update all the rows in the table in one fell swoop, using an UPDATE with a JOIN operation, as in the example I provided.

Comment: I have a table with 30000 unique strings to change but we can find those strings in other tables (15-20) known to me as well as the columns in them that contain the strings. So I suppose that if I run the before mentioned solution table by table I will have my solution. I was wondering if there is a solution that can make the update at once?

Comment: @ChrisSkliris: updating more than one column in a table could be done, the SQL for that is a little more involved. You'd want to use an outer join, and the value you assign would to the column would need to be an expression. Assuming you aren't replacing non-NULL values with NULL values, you could do `SET t.col = IFNULL(s.new_value,t.col)`, so unmatched rows would retain their existing values. There would have to be some compelling reason for me to update more than one table in the same statement, otherwise, that's way more work than it's worth.

Comment: @ChrisSkliris: Every UPDATE statement is going to have to specify the **tables** and **columns** to be updated. That list has to come from somewhere; there's no SQL statement that will update indeterminate columns in indeterminate tables. The table name and column name have to be *specified* in the SQL statement. That means you need a list of tables and columns to be updated. I mentioned the `information_schema` database in an earlier comment, and I'm not sure that was available before MySQL 5.1.x.

Comment: Your solution worked fine up until i faced the following problem: the string_column is declared as unique key. I tried to change the values in there but it rejected the code since there where same values in the new_value column. Can i by pass this problem by disabling temporarly the unique key and then inforcing it back or it will end up with double values? Any suggestion?

Comment: @ChrisSkliris: You'd end up with double values, and you wouldn't be able to re-establish the UNIQUE constraint. I suggest you modify the contents of your **`old_new`** table to ensure the new values are unique. Identify the duplicate "new" values... `SELECT t.newval FROM old_new t GROUP BY t.newval HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`, and fix those. Or, there are existing rows in the the target table that have values in the "newval" column of `old_new`, but there's no corresponding "oldval" entry in `old_new` that will replace the existing value.

Comment: I do'nt know if i was lucky but by disabling unique (in one table) and primary (in another one) and reeforcing them it worked (until know). I thought i would end up with a loop but using SyQLyog it seems it worked.